# NoSql and too big documents

Tags: nosql

It's a very common example, that if we have `Posts` and `Comments` in NoSql world, it's a good solution to store `Comments` inside the `Post` document (because comments doesn't make much sense on their own).

But what if it's relatively common to have a lot of comments per post? If it happens that there are about 10000 comments for some posts on my blog engine. Comments are paged, so I don't need all the 10000 at once.

Is it good to load the complete document in that case? What are the solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have much experience with NoSQL databases (only worked a bit with MongoDB), but I believe you are looking for pagination.

Since you haven't mentioned which NoSQL database you are looking for, here's are some ways you can do it:

- MongoDB: http://shakthydoss.wordpress.com/2011/06/20/pagination-with-mongodb/
- CouchDB: [Creating a pagination index in CouchDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3647101/creating-a-pagination-index-in-couchdb)

In most cases, you may need to create a pagniation index before you can use pagination.

Comment: thanks, I thought there's no such thing as pagination within a document :)